Relationship between power series coefficients
We work over formal power series over $K=\mathbb{C}$. Fix some non-zero constant $k\in K$. Let $A(t)$ be a formal power series in $K[t]$ with zero constant term. Then, we can consider the formal logarithm:
$$\ln(1+A(t)) = B(t),$$
for some power series $B(t)$. Similarly, we can consider the formal logarithm:
$$\ln(1+kA(t)) = C(t),$$
for some other power series $C(t)$.
My question is, is there a nice relationship between the coefficients of $B(t)$ and $C(t)$? For example, just comparing powers of $t$ in both of these equalities, it is clear that the coefficients of $C(t)$ are polynomial in those of $B(t)$. These are some universal polynomials (that is, they don't depend on $A(t)$) depending on $k$. So, my specific question is, are these polynomials known to be related to any standard sequence of polynomials?
For example, if $B(t)=\sum_{n\geq 1} b_nt^n$ and $C(t)=\sum_{n\geq 1} c_nt^n$, then we can observe that:
$$c_1 = kb_1$$
$$c_2 = kb_2 - \frac{k^2-k}{2}b_1$$
$$c_3 = kb_3 - (k^2-k)b_1b_2 + \frac{k(k-1)(2k-1)}{6}b_1^3, \cdots$$
I am looking for a nice way for writing these polynomials, or just any other way of computing the power series $C(t)$ from $B(t)$.

Formally, for $k \geq 1$ an integer at the very least, we can see that: $$C_k(t) - C_{k - 1}(t) = \ln \left(1 + \frac{A(t)}{1 + (k-1) A(t)}\right)$$ so that: $$C_k(t) = \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} \ln \left(1 + \frac{A(t)}{1 + (j-1) A(t)}\right)$$ which might explain why the coefficients in front of the products of $b_n$s in the expansions you mentioned are of the type $\sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} j^m$ for some $m$ but this doesn't prove anything yet.
